# Return Parent Index of matching Selected elements

Tags: xml, vb.net, linq, linq-to-xml

I have an XML as Follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?>
<DataTable Uid="dtPlan">
  <Rows>
    <Row>
      <Cells>
        <Cell>
          <ColumnUid>ItemCode</ColumnUid>
          <Value>item1</Value>
        </Cell>
        <Cell>
          <ColumnUid>Price</ColumnUid>
          <Value>22</Value>
        </Cell>
      </Cells>
    </Row>
    <Row>
      <Cells>
        <Cell>
          <ColumnUid>ItemCode</ColumnUid>
          <Value>item2</Value>
        </Cell>
        <Cell>
          <ColumnUid>Price</ColumnUid>
          <Value>24</Value>
        </Cell>        
      </Cells>
    </Row>
    <Row>
      <Cells>
        <Cell>
          <ColumnUid>ItemCode</ColumnUid>
          <Value>item1</Value>
        </Cell>        
        <Cell>
          <ColumnUid>Price</ColumnUid>
          <Value>22</Value>
        </Cell>
      </Cells>
    </Row>
  </Rows>
</DataTable>
```

From this i would like to return those with ItemCodes that match, which i can do with this query:

```
    Dim queryResult = From x In xDoc.Descendants("Cell")
    Where x.Element("ColumnUid").Value = "ItemCode" AndAlso x.Element("Value") = "item1"
    Select x
```

what i am also wishing to do is return the index for the row element `<Row>`  the items were selected from, so for the above example it should return 1 & 3

there are three `<Row>` elements in the xml so if the query matches the items in `<Row>` 1 and `<Row>` 3, return 1 & 3 (or 0 and 2).

i have tried using:

```
    Dim queryResult = From x In xDoc.Descendants("Cell")
    Where x.Element("ColumnUid").Value = "ItemCode" AndAlso x.Element("Value") = "item1"
    Select x.ElementsBeforeSelf().Count()
```

But this only returns the same value twice, is there a way to return the row index using a linq query?

Comment: You can probably write something like: `dim qr = xDoc.Descendants("Cell").Select(Function(x, n) New With {Key .Id = n + 1, .e = x}).Where(Function(an) an.e.Element("ColumnUid").Value = "ItemCode" AndAlso an.e.Element("Value").Value = "item1")`. From the XML you posted, you have matching `Cell` elements in (0, 4) or (1, 5), not (1, 3)

Comment: You're missing a *piece* here: `AndAlso x.Element("Value")`, so you probably have Option Strict Off.

Comment: Thanks Jimi, does this return the index for the <Row> element the matching items where selected from? apologies if my question was unclear, i have updated it.

Comment: See that `Function(x, n)`? `x` is the current xElement, `n` is the progressive order of the `xDocument.Descendants("Cell")` elements. In the end, `qr(0).Id` is the Row index of the first match. Unless with `Row` you mean the *line of text* in the XML file. Then no.

Comment: hi, are you talking about the Row Index meaning line number of the XML? i think i am after something different,   my xml only has three <Row> elements so the answer would need to be 1 & 3  or (0 & 2).

Comment: Ah! No, that was not what the code suggested. You have to extract the `<Row>` elements for that thing to work, not just the `<Cell>` elements. The code snippet I posted keeps track of the `<Cell>` elements index.

Comment: ah i think we're on the right track, so change xDoc.Descendants("Cell") to xDoc.Descendants("Row") and then work some magic?

Comment: Well, pretty much. It could be something along the line: `dim qr = xDoc.Descendants("Row").Select(Function(xr, n) New With {Key .Id = n + 1, .Cells = xr.Descendants("Cell").Where(Function(xe) xe.Element("ColumnUid").Value = "ItemCode" AndAlso xe.Element("Value").Value = "item1")}).Where(Function(an) an.Cells.Any())`. Now, this groups all matching `<Cell>` elements in a Row based on the `<Row>` index. If you need to retrieve single cells with a potentially duplicate index, `Select()` further (or `SelectMany()` to flatten the inner collections).

Comment: Try : Dim queryResult = From x In xDoc.Descendants("Row").SelectMany(Function(x, i) x.Descendants("Cell").Where(Function(y) y.Element("ColumnUid").Value = "ItemCode" AndAlso x.Element("Value") = "item1").Select(Function(y) New With {.cell = y, .item = i})).ToList()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
    Dim foo As XElement
    foo = <DataTable Uid="dtPlan">
              <Rows>
                  <Row>
                      <Cells>
                          <Cell>
                              <ColumnUid>ItemCode</ColumnUid>
                              <Value>item1</Value>
                          </Cell>
                          <Cell>
                              <ColumnUid>Price</ColumnUid>
                              <Value>22</Value>
                          </Cell>
                      </Cells>
                  </Row>
                  <Row>
                      <Cells>
                          <Cell>
                              <ColumnUid>ItemCode</ColumnUid>
                              <Value>item2</Value>
                          </Cell>
                          <Cell>
                              <ColumnUid>Price</ColumnUid>
                              <Value>24</Value>
                          </Cell>
                      </Cells>
                  </Row>
                  <Row>
                      <Cells>
                          <Cell>
                              <ColumnUid>ItemCode</ColumnUid>
                              <Value>item1</Value>
                          </Cell>
                          <Cell>
                              <ColumnUid>Price</ColumnUid>
                              <Value>22</Value>
                          </Cell>
                      </Cells>
                  </Row>
              </Rows>
          </DataTable>

    Dim allCells As List(Of XElement) = (From c In foo...<Cell>
                                            Where c.<ColumnUid>.Value = "ItemCode"
                                            Select c).ToList

    Dim queryResult As IEnumerable(Of XElement)
    queryResult = From x In allCells
                    Where x.<Value>.Value = "item1"
                    Select x


    For Each el As XElement In queryResult
        Dim idx As Integer
        idx = (From x In allCells Where x.Equals(el) Select allCells.IndexOf(x) Take 1).FirstOrDefault
        Debug.WriteLine(idx.ToString)
    Next
```